# How do I pass parameters to custom log formatters using pythons logging configuration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

In my python project, I have a custom Log formatter which I'd like to pass a string to at construction, and for it to add that to the message it's logging out:

```
class MyCustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyCustomFormatter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    print(f'configuring {args} {kwargs}')

    if 'constants' in kwargs:
        self.constants = kwargs.get('constants')
```

I am configuring my logging using the logging.yml configuration provided by python:

```
version: 1
formatters:
    standardFormatter:
        class: MyCustomFormatter
        constants: "constants"
handlers:
    consoleHandler:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: INFO
        formatter: standardFormatter
        stream: ext://sys.stdout
root:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [consoleHandler]
```

I was expecting 'constants' to be passed in the kwargs to MyCustomFormatter.**init**, however kwargs seems to be empty.  How do I configure a value in the logging config and have that passed to my formatter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unknown keys that are found in the logging dict are only passed as kwargs to the constructor for handlers or when using [custom instantiation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#user-defined-objects) with the special `()` key. So in your case you would need to configure your formatter like this:

```
formatters:
    standardFormatter:
        (): importpath.for.MyCustomFormatter
        constants: constants
```

I would recomend though to not use `dictConfig` at all and go with `fileConfig`, which makes a lot of special cases like this easier.